# granting keyvault access to datafactory from azure deploy task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

When using this command, we are forced to reconnect with credentials:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy –VaultName 'valueName' –ObjectId 'objectId'
–PermissionsToSecrets get -Passthru
```

This forces us to use this following command, otherwise we will get a `credentials expired` message:

`Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential 'credentials'`

**How do we prevent re-authentication?**

Comment: Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy does a graph call to check that the ObjectId is valid,may be your graph token is missing.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT how would one verify that?

Comment: Isn't the task using a service connection?

Comment: Does it succeed when you re-authenticate?